# What is the alternative of Apache's global Alias in IIS instead of adding a Virtual Directory to every single sites one by one?

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, alias

In Apache, there's a way I can make phpMyAdmin available globally to all VirtualHosts I set up. In Apache, it looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/AppServ/www/phpMyAdmin"
</IfModule>
```

This way I reach phpmyadmin with **prepending /phpmyadmin to all my domain names**, and I can see phpmyadmin's initial page. (So for example it works for all my domains like this: `http://example_1.com/phpmyadmin`, `http://example_2.com/phpmyadmin`, `http://example_3.com/phpmyadmin` also does work).

In IIS, there's an *"**Add Virtual Directory...**"* option when right clicking on a given site. Here I can set up e.g. phpMyAdmin's path to be reached with prepending /phpmyadmin to the given domain (e.g. `http://example_1.com/phpmyadmin`), but isn't there a "**global**" setting similar to Apache's Alias?

Or do I have to add a virtual directory to every given sites one by one?
I'm just curious, it's not a hard work to do it, but I'm interested in it if there exists another method to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, IIS directory and virtual directory paths are not normally case-sensitive so you can get by creating a virtual directory named "phpmyadmin" and use /phpMyAdmin, /phpmyadmin, /PHPMyAdmin or any other combination of case and you'll get the expected content.

Comment: No, you didn't understand the question. :D I just want /phpmyadmin to be available GLOBALLY, across many-many sites. So for example I have 15 domains, with 15 different physical paths, but I want to make phpmyadmin available for all the 15 sites. I can do this globally with Apache's Alias directive for all the VirtualHosts I have set up. I'm curious if I could do it with IIS 7.5 too, without having to set the virtual directory in every single sites. (It's not that difficult to do it, but I'm interested if I could do it in another way.) I hope I could explain it now a little bit better. :)

Comment: OK, I edited my original question not to be misunderstood, I hope this one is better now...

Comment: Oh, OK.  My mistake.  I don't believe you can do it globally--you would have to create each virtual directory underneath each site.